# RegEx for capturing a pattern with new lines

Tags: regex, string, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regex-greedy

I have the following string

```
1h 30min: Title 
- Description Line 1
1h 30min: Title
- Description Line 1
- Description Line 2
- Description Line 3
```

And I would like to get the following results using regex.

```
Match 1:
  "1h 30min: Title 
  - Description Line 1"

      Group 1: "1h"
      Group 2: "30min"
      Group 3: "Title 
               - Description Line 1"
```

```
Match 2:
  "1h 30min: Title 
  - Description Line 1
  - Description Line 2
  - Description Line 3"

      Group 1: "1h"
      Group 2: "30min"
      Group 3: "Title 
               - Description Line 1
               - Description Line 2
               - Description Line 3"
```

I have the following regex https://regex101.com/r/dp5zKq/1

```
(([0-9]{1,2}h)\s*([0-9]{1,2}min)*\:)+?((.*\n*)*)
```

However I can't figure out how to make the any character / new line regex stop when it hits a new match for the hours & minutes. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi Emma, the desired output is in the question underneath "And I would like to match the following using regex". It lists the desired matches and groups.

Comment: I've updated it to "I would like to get the following results using regex" for clarity.

Comment: Another one: [`(\d+h)\s*(\d+min):\s*(.*(?:\n-.*)*)`](https://regex101.com/r/Vn5Sb7/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could match the h and min parts in group 1 and 2.

Then use a repeating pattern that matches the whole line if it does not start with the hour pattern (or include the minute afterwards as well.

```
([0-9]{1,2}h)[ ]*([0-9]{1,2}min):[ ]*(.*(?:\n(?![0-9]{1,2}h).*)*)
```

**Explanation**

- `([0-9]{1,2}h)[ ]*` Capturing group 1, the h format
- `([0-9]{1,2}min)` Capturing group 2, the min format
- `:[ ]*` Match : and 1+ spaces (the space does not have to be in a character class, this is only for clarity)
- `(` Capturing group 3

  - `.*` Match any char except a newline 0+ times
  - `(?:` Non capturing group
  - `\n(?![0-9]{1,2}h).*` Match a newline, assert what is on the right is not the h pattern. If it is not, match any char except a newline 0+ times
  - `)` Close non capturing group and repeat 0+ times
- `)` Close group 3

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eXx5Zy/1)

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing this might be an expression that would be desired or close to:

```
([\s\S]*?)(([0-9]{1,2}h)\s*([0-9]{1,2}min)*\:)?
```

#### [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/hI1Gg2/1)

Comment: This is very close, however, each character is being grouped individually after the hours / minutes. Is possible to group them as a single string?

Comment: Thanks the fourth bird has got the correct result. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can modify your regex a little to use a positive lookahead to stop before a time string or end of input using this regex and also use `[\w\W]` to capture multiple lines,

```
([0-9]{1,2}h)\s*([0-9]{1,2}min)*:\s*([\w\W]*?)(?=[0-9]{1,2}h\s*([0-9]{1,2}min)|$)
```

**[Regex Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/dp5zKq/2)**

OR

Even a better regex if time can appear within a description anywhere, you can use this regex, which uses multiline mode and in lookahead uses `^` to ensure it doesn't stop if time is present in the description anywhere and uses `\Z` to mark the absolute end of string.

```
([0-9]{1,2}h)\s*([0-9]{1,2}min)*:\s*([\w\W]*?)(?=^[0-9]{1,2}h\s*[0-9]{1,2}min|\Z)
```

**[Regex Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/dp5zKq/4)**

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: This seems to match the 31mins in the first group. The fourth bird seems to have got it working.

Comment: @RyanKing: 31mins is matched exactly in second group. Can you check again? My regex is working like you expected. `1h` is captured in group1 and `31min` in group2.

Comment: Look at `group 4` of `match 1`

Comment: @RyanKing: Group4 was actually redundant and not needed. I've removed that useless grouping as that was not needed anyway in a positive lookahead.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: @RyanKing: It was already working fine but just had an unneeded group4 in lookahead. Thank you for acknowledging :)